# Php Group Data Idea

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, grouping

how can group date and calculate sum of weight then put assoc array php?

```
{name:"A",date:"2012-12-11",order:1,time:3,weight:10},
{name:"A",date:"2012-12-11",order:1,time:4,weight:12},
{name:"B",date:"2012-12-11",order:1,time:3,weight:17},
{name:"A",date:"2012-12-12",order:1,time:5,weight:50},
{name:"A",date:"2012-12-12",order:2,time:3,weight:70}
```

According this sum of weight day by day but problem is if(same date same order same name ; which one greater time take its weight, dont care less) but different name or order take sum of group.

Result must be like:

```
{date:2012-12-11,weight:29},
{date:2012-12-12,weight:120},
```

Anyone Help ?
it can be like

```
{name:"A",date:"2012-12-11",order:1,time:3,weight:10}, 
{name:"B",date:"2012-12-11",order:1,time:3,weight:17},
{name:"A",date:"2012-12-11‌​",order:1,time:4,weight:12},
 {name:"A",date:"2012-12-12",order:1,time:5,weight:50},
 {name:"A",date:"2012-12-12",order:2,time:3,weight:70}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two things,  [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$arr = json_decode($data, true);  // `true` makes an associative array
```

And [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
usort($arr, "sortfcn");
```

...where `sortfcn` is a string with the name of a custom function for your sorting:

```
function sortfcn($a, $b) {
    if ($a['date'] > $b['date') { return 1; }
    else if ($a['date'] < $b['date']) { return -1; } 

    return 0;
}
```

I haven't tested these but that's the main idea, have a look at the docs to clear up my syntax errors and get a better idea of the thing.  It will definitely do what you want.

Summing the weight is a simple matter of `foreach`ing through the sorted array and adding it up.

Comment: but if name and order is same we gonna care greater time's weight . did you see what i want do in result ?

Comment: it can be like  
{name:"A",date:"2012-12-11",order:1,time:3,weight:10},
{name:"B",date:"2012-12-11",order:1,time:3,weight:17},{name:"A",date:"2012-12-11",order:1,time:4,weight:12},
{name:"A",date:"2012-12-12",order:1,time:5,weight:50},
{name:"A",date:"2012-12-12",order:2,time:3,weight:70}

Comment: @user - yes, so you can do whatever you want in the `sortfcn`.  So, something like `if ($a['date'] == $b['date']) { if ($a['weight'] > $b['weight']) { return 1; } }`.  Have a look at the provieded documentation links, please, and you'll see what I mean.